# date is running in +5:30

Tags: java, date, time, timezone

i am using this in my Class

```
@Required
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date startDate;

@Required
@JsonFormat(pattern = "HH:mm:ss")
private Date startTime;
```

but when i passed

```
"startDate": "2015-06-26","startTime": "16:00:35"
```

from frontend and cast to object

then i see

```
Long start=obj.getStartDate().getTime()+obj.getStartTime().getTime();

System.out.println(new Date(start));
//Fri Jun 26 21:30:35 IST 2015

System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
//Fri Jun 26 18:50:27 IST 2015
```

that its in +5:30

i just want to test it is before the current time or not.
please suggest best practice.

Comment: You need the timezone as well - at least if it can be different from the system's timezone (which seems to be IST in your case).

Comment: @Thomas in case if i Set timezone to IST  then its -5:30

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need time zone information take a look at the `LocalDateTime` or if you need time zone info: `ZonedDateTime` class in the JAVA-8 or if you are using 7 or before look at the joda version

Answer (score 0):

## Correct Behavior

Your code is performing correctly (presumably, as you do not show all of it).

You specified a time of `16:00:35` which is then parsed (apparently) as UTC time zone. That `Long` object contains a count of milliseconds since epoch of 1970 *in UTC*.

When adjusted to India time zone, five and a half hours ahead of UTC, we correctly see `21:30:35` on same date.

## Use A Decent Library

The old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

To make life easier, learn to use a decent date-time library. In Java, that means either:

- java.time package built into Java 8 and later.
- Joda-Time library

Search StackOverflow for many many examples of either.

## Avoid Time Zone Codes

Avoid using, or even thinking about, those 3-4 letter time zone codes. They are neither standardized nor unique. They further confuse Daylight Saving Time. By `IST` did you mean `India Standard Time` or `Irish Standard Time` or maybe `Iran Standard Time`?

Instead use only [proper time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), in format of `continent/city-or-region`. For example, `"Asia/Kolkata"`.

## Pad Offset

You incorrectly stated the India time zone as `+5:30`. In an offset-from-UTC, the **leading zero is not optional**. India offset is `+05:30`.